# SkyDrive & Visual Studio 2012 syncing issues

Tags: visual-studio-2012, onedrive

I am trying to host all my projects on the cloud, and I am having problems with the names syncing with each other.  If I edit a file, it doesn't know.  Why doesn't it push a SkyDrive update?

If there is an alternative (free) to SkyDrive & VS, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/) for the past few years to hold my projects and I've never had any issues with it. Heck, if you also needed a SVN repository, you could set up TortoiseSVN, on it and [use Dropbox as a repository](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dropbox-svn-subversion-repository/). Of course they only give you 2GB of storage for free (which can be increased via referrals). I have around 16 websites and projects on there, as well as other documents and I'm not using 10% of what I have (about 3.2GB).

Answer (score 3):

If you are the one who own the projects, I suggest you to create Bitbucket account. You can store unlimited private repositories for free unless you have more than 3 developers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also keep you code in the source control hosted on the cloud. I have been using free [TFS online](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/) which also supports Git. It works seamlessly with Visual Studio 2012.